# Iterate unique sets of integers

Tags: algorithms, counting, iteration

I'm trying to figure out of if there's a way to generate all unique sets of integers of length K, where each member has an upper bound of N, and a lower bound of M, without tracking which sets have already been generated, where the order doesn't matter.

To be clear: I'm not looking for ways to filter duplicates from a pre-computed set of sets.

I'm asking if there is an algorithmic approach to generate the unique combinations of values, without producing duplicate combinations/repetitions along the way that must be tested for and removed.

For example, I wrote this counter, which will generate all sets of length K with members bounded at N, but with duplicates.

JavaScript:

```
function count(k, n, m = 0) {
    // Create counting columns
    let cols = Array(k).fill(m);
    let rows = [];
    
    while (true) {
        rows.push(cols.slice(0));
                
        for (let j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
            ++cols[j];
            
            if (cols[j] <= n) {
                break;
            } else if (j === k - 1) {
                return rows;
            }
            
            // If no overflow, reset column and increment the next on next loop
            cols[j] = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
> let k=3, n=5, m=1

> count(k, n, m).join('\n');

"1,1,1
2,1,1
3,1,1
1,2,1
2,2,1
3,2,1
1,3,1
2,3,1
3,3,1
1,1,2
2,1,2
3,1,2
1,2,2
2,2,2
3,2,2
1,3,2
2,3,2
3,3,2
1,1,3
2,1,3
3,1,3
1,2,3
2,2,3
3,2,3
1,3,3
2,3,3
3,3,3"
```

But, as you can see, that produces 1,2,3 as well as 3,2,1.

An example case: if I'm searching for sums of cubes that equal a cube, I don't need to test `2^3 + 16^3 + 12^3 = 18^3` if I've already checked that `2^3 + 12^3 + 16^3 = 18^3`.

So I wouldn't want to generate an equivalent set again after having already tested an alternate order of the same terms.

Many thanks.

Comment: If I understood correctly it looks like you have a set $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ and want to list all combinations of $k$ elements allowing repetitions. See [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions) for example.

Comment: @plop - Thanks - If I understand you and that page correctly, then no, that's not what I'm looking for. I've updated my answer some more - is that more clear? I apologise, I'm not very familiar with proper terminology.

Comment: @thephpdev to clarify for {1,2,3,4} as your numbers and choosing k = 3 as the size of the subsets {1,2,2} wouldn't be valid?

Comment: Do you have a set of distinct integers?

Comment: If that's not what you are looking for, can you tell us what you *are* looking for, and give a clear statement of the task?

Comment: (Depending on [context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), you can ignore the mechanics.) (Your edit killed a more verbose introduction.)

Comment: @STanja - no, I'm talking about generating them without tracking which combinations have been generated already

Comment: @D.W. - done, please check again.

Comment: @greybeard - thanks I'll take a look at that

Comment: @thephpdev to me it's still not clear if you want to have {1,1,2} (duplicate elements in a set) or not. I understand that you don't want {1,2,3} and {3,2,1} (duplicate sets). But what about duplicate elements?

Comment: @plshelp - Duplicate elements are fine, duplicate sets are not. After the correction your answer seems to be working. I'll pick this up tomorrow

Comment: @greybeard - also, your suggestion solves the problem too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick to achieve this. Basically you always keep the subset you are currently considering sorted.

```
subset = [];
function forSubsets(n,k,m=1){
  if(subset.length == k) console.log(subset);
  else{
    for(var i = m; i <= n; i++){
      subset.push(i);
      forSubsets(n,k,i);
      subset.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see on each recursion one element is added to the subset, which is equal or bigger than all previous elements (since the loop starts from m where m is the previously added element). The order for `forSubsets(3,2)` would be
[1,1]; [1,2]; [1,3]; [2,2]; [2,3]; [3,3];
Of course you have to adapt the implementation to your programming language, but I hope the recursive idea is understandable. `yield` syntax could also be used to implement this concept in a readable manner (e.g. Python). StackOverflow should be a better place for implementation details. By changing the bounds in the for-loop the you could also draw the subsets from $0,...,n-1$ instead of $1,...,n$.

Just for the sake of completeness: Here is the code for generating subsets without duplicate elements (but no duplicate subsets):

```
subset = [];
function forSubsets(n,k,m=0){
  if(subset.length == k) console.log(subset);
  else{
    for(var i = m+1; i <= n-k+1+subset.length; i++){
      subset.push(i);
      forSubsets(n,k,i);
      subset.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this out and got some weird results. I've added some concrete examples into my questions. For n = 5 and k = 3 I get: "1,2,3,4,5;
1,2,3,4,6;
1,2,3,4,7;
1,2,3,5,6;
1,2,3,5,7 ..."

If I'm being a silly billy and missing something about your proposed solution, please do tell me!

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the code; I'll corrected right now.

Comment: @thephpdev possible error sources are that you didn't use <= in the loop; you use subset.length == n instead of subset.length == k; you mutate subset; if nothing helps I can send you working C++ or python code.

Comment: yeah that works now. Many thanks

Comment: Hi - Sorry, I didn't look closely enough at the values. This seems to exclude sets with duplicate elements, as well as duplicate sets - this must be why you asked!. Not too worry though @greybeard posted an approach which does the job. My implementation, to be sure I'm not missing anything: https://pastebin.com/S3MF7PXY

Comment: Not a bad thing though it adds another answer on a keyword laden page for any future Googlers. Kind of a tricky thing to search for if you're not sure on terms. Thank you for your time, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see you've updated this with the version that skips duplicate sets but allows duplicate elements. Accepted as that works nicely. Many thanks.

Comment: I must add - now that I get it it's a beautifully simple solution!